# Java resultSet getInt() returns no value

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, swing, jtable

Here, resultSet.getInt() doesn't work, but I do not know what is wrong with my code.

I want to increment the value of the column (with the name as the variable 'attendance'). Using the SELECT statement I want to read the current value and by using UPDATE I want to increment the corresponding value by 1. But the problem is that int a = r.getInt("'" + attendance + "'"); doesn't work. It always returns the value 0 although the current value isn't 0 (e.g. 1). What is wrong with my code?

```
try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                     c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+ x +".db");
                     s = c.createStatement();
                     r = s.executeQuery("SELECT '" + attendance + "' FROM viewer WHERE name = '" + name + "' AND year = '" + year + "'");
                     while (r.next()){
                         int a = r.getInt("'" + attendance + "'");
                         int b = 1 + a;
                         String sql = "UPDATE viewer SET '" + attendance + "' = ? WHERE name = ? AND year = ? ";
                         p = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                         p.setInt (1,b);
                         p.setString (2,name);
                         p.setInt (3,year);
                         p.executeUpdate();
                     }
                     p.close();
                     c.close();
                     // r.getInt()  value always 0
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wrap the name of the column in single quotes, it is considered as the string literal `'attendance'` and not the name of the column which is the value of the variable `attendance`.
Change to:

```
"SELECT " + attendance + " FROM viewer WHERE name = '" + name + "' AND year = '" + year + "'"
```

(why do you concatenate the arguments `name` and `year`? Use placeholders `?` just like the `UPDATE` statement)
and

```
"UPDATE viewer SET " + attendance + " = ? WHERE name = ? AND year = ? "
```

and

```
int a = r.getInt(attendance);
```

Answer (score 0):

since you only have 1 column, you can use `column index`, instead of column names

```
int a = r.getInt(0);
```

Comment: attendance is the variable... for instance if attendance = present, present is the column name